# Formatting required value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have

```
var val = "2520,3569,99991,14203,11918";
```

also
my tests contains all the values in below format (attached the screenshot), which contains all the tests values.
In that complete list, I need only a few values, which I can filter it by below string. that means if I have any of the above ids, I have to consider it.

For example, if my tests contains any of the value from:

`var val= "2520,3569,99991,14203,11918";` ,  then I need it like
`2520.1|3569.0|99991.1|14203.0|11918.0`,

Ignoring all other values. 
(where 2520 is id and 1/0 is value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var myObject = [{
    bucketValue: 1,
    exprimentId: 56988
  }, {
    bucketValue: 1,
    exprimentId: 2520
  }, {
    bucketValue: 0,
    exprimentId: 3569
  }, {
    bucketValue: 1,
    exprimentId: 99991
  }, {
    bucketValue: 0,
    exprimentId: 14203
  }, {
    bucketValue: 0,
    exprimentId: 11918
  }, {
    bucketValue: 1,
    exprimentId: 1111
  }, {
    bucketValue: 0,
    exprimentId: 22222
  }];

  var marketingABTests = "2520,3569,99991,14203,11918";

  var myValues = marketingABTests.split(",");

  var myFinalValue = "";

  for (i = 0; i < myValues.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < myObject.length; j++) {
      //alert(myValues[i] + "     " + myObject[j].exprimentId);
      if (myFinalValue == "" && myValues[i].toString().trim() == myObject[j].exprimentId.toString().trim()) {
        myFinalValue = myObject[j].exprimentId.toString().trim() + "." + myObject[j].bucketValue.toString().trim();
      } else if (myFinalValue != "" && myValues[i].toString().trim() == myObject[j].exprimentId.toString().trim()) {
        myFinalValue = myFinalValue + "|" + myObject[j].exprimentId.toString().trim() + "." + myObject[j].bucketValue.toString().trim();
      }

    }
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFinalValue;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="demo">

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is you want, try this answer,

```js
marketingABTests = "2520,3569,99991,14203,11918".split(",");
expABTests = [
 {
   "experimentId" : 2520,
   "bucketValue" : 1,
 },
 {
   "experimentId" : 3569,
   "bucketValue" : 0,
 },
 {
   "experimentId" : 11918,
   "bucketValue" : 0,
 },
 {
   "experimentId" : 99991,
   "bucketValue" : 1,
 }
]
newMarketABTest = ""
for (var i in marketingABTests) {
  curr_i =  eval(marketingABTests[i]);
  find_val = _.find(expABTests, function(num) { return num.experimentId == curr_i });
  if(find_val) {
    newMarketABTest+= find_val.experimentId+"."+find_val.bucketValue+"|"  
    }
}
newMarketABTest = newMarketABTest.substring(0, newMarketABTest.length - 1);
console.log(newMarketABTest);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```